# MSc admission in Canada

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

Is meeting the entry (minimal) requirements of MSc in pharmacy in Canada enough to get accepted into the program? (For extracurricular activities: I have dozens of certificates of online webinars I've attended, 2 online courses and some conferences and I will take both IELTS & TOEFL exams)
Is it enough?

Comment: These kind of things depend on individual factors. I'm not sure if you'll get the required answer on this site.

Comment: Most universities will explicitly tell you that simply "meeting entry requirements" is not sufficient for admission.

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough, in the sense that it does not guarantee admission.  It simply means your file will be considered.

Admission to a program will vary from one university to the next, depending on number of applicants, financial resources available, supervisory resources availability, lab benches etc.

Comment: Also, for purely course-based master's (i.e. where there is no need for supervisor involvement, lab space, etc.) it would come down to the capacity of the program and the *relative* quality of the qualified applicants (assuming that there are more than enough applicants to fill the program)

Comment: @BenBolker course-based degrees might still have lab components: say there might be only so-many high-end oscilloscopes or oscillators available for some electronics course.  However you are likely broadly right that, given the financial rewards to the university: such programs usually function near capacity.